# Numpy load and save ijv (row-column-value) format

Tags: matrix, numpy

I would like to read a file into a numpy matrix. In this file each row has the structure "row;col;value", so a matrix like

```
m = numpy.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

would be in a file that starts with the following lines:

```
0;0;1
0;1;2
0;2;3
1;0;4
...
```

I have found no built in way of loading and saving such files in Numpy and doing that manually might be very slow. Which way would you suggest?

Comment: Do it "manually" (it is really simple) and don't worry about it unless it ever becomes a bottleneck. I just tried that and it's not annoyingly slow for arrays below 1000x1000. If you're storing so much redundant information I guess your matrices are small. BTW, is it "row;col;val" or "col;row;val" as in the example?

Comment: Yes, it is row;col;val. This format is just one of many I need to load. We used it at work sometimes and I thought being able to handle it as well for this hobby project might be good. Is it that uncommon to store matrices in such a fashion?

Comment: I hadn't seen it, at least not for dense matrices. You can get the same information storing the matrix shape in the first line and then all values in a convenient order, like `2 3\n1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Comment: I understand that it makes not much sense for dense matrices, but at least scipy supports sparse matrices and should support the format. Anyways, thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: scipy can read a couple of sparse matrix formats (see `scipy.io`) but not your format, which is essentially the one "being phased out" in the [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#coord) because it's not very space efficient. Feel free to answer your question when possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way. As pointed out in the comments it's often much faster to save the shape and then a flat 1D version of the matrix. But doing it manually is not a tremendous bottleneck unless your matrix is huge. There are many ways to do it, here's an example with `numpy.nditer`:

```
m = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
it = np.nditer(m, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    f.write('%i;%i;%i\n' % (it.multi_index[0], it.multi_index[1], it[0]))
    it.iternext()
```

This would give:

```
0;0;1
0;1;2
0;2;3
1;0;4
1;1;5
1;2;6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build some simple functions to do these conversions:

```
def to_ijv(a):
    rows, cols = a.shape
    ijv = np.empty((a.size,), dtype=[('i', np.intp),
                                     ('j', np.intp),
                                     ('v', a.dtype)])
    ijv['i'] = np.repeat(np.arange(rows), cols)
    ijv['j'] = np.tile(np.arange(cols), rows)
    ijv['v'] = a.ravel()
    return ijv

def from_ijv(ijv):
    rows, cols = np.max(ijv['i']) + 1, np.max(ijv['j']) + 1
    a = np.empty((rows, cols), dtype=ijv['v'].dtype)
    a[ijv['i'], ijv['j']] = ijv['v']
    return a
```

If your matrices are large, you can use the built-in `loadtxt` and `savetxt` to read and write to disk:

```
def save_ijv(file_, a):
    ijv = to_ijv(a)
    np.savetxt(file_, ijv, delimiter=';', fmt=('%d', '%d', '%f'))

def read_ijv(file_):
    ijv = np.loadtxt(file_, delimiter=';',
                     dtype=[('i', np.intp),('j', np.intp),
                            ('v', np.float)])
    return from_ijv(ijv)
```

These functions have a liking for floating point numbers, so you will have to explicitly edit the format if you want e.g. integers. Other than that it works nicely:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(3, 2)
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> to_ijv(a)
array([(0L, 0L, 1), (0L, 1L, 2), (1L, 0L, 3), (1L, 1L, 4), (2L, 0L, 5),
       (2L, 1L, 6)], 
      dtype=[('i', '<i8'), ('j', '<i8'), ('v', '<i4')])
>>> import StringIO as sio
>>> file_ = sio.StringIO()
>>> save_ijv(file_, a)
>>> print file_.getvalue()
0;0;1.000000
0;1;2.000000
1;0;3.000000
1;1;4.000000
2;0;5.000000
2;1;6.000000

>>> file_.pos = 0
>>> b = read_ijv(file_)
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])
```